# Batch File not working in windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

[image]I have a simple batch files that executes when run manually, however when run via task scheduler it errors with a 0x1 code.

Comment: Try using double quotes around the path of batch file. if current working directory matters, set it correctly from task scheduler. And if you share more (like path, error message), someone will help you

Comment: 1. remove `@echo off` in the batch file and append `pause` to it, so you might already see what causes the failure; 2. provide (sample) code of the batch file; 3. it would be very helpful if you'd describe the Windows Task Scheduler settings;

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck the box that says "Run whether user is logged in or not."

Certain batch functions require permissions to actually work, so if this is being run while no user is logged in, it can cause an error due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: Code: for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%I in ("%date%") do set todaysdate=%%L%%J%%K

set filename=UACC%todaysdate%.in1

move /y "C:\Lexis Nexis\%filename%" "Z:\LOSS MITIGATION\Automated Scrubs\BK Scrub Lexis Nexis\UPLOAD FILES\2015-06"

Comment: It certainly looks like what you're doing requires elevated privileges, so perhaps you need to store the password.